# Помогите проблема c Header()

Tags: php, header

Помогите проблема c Header(). Как правильно сделать?

```
header("Location: <?php echo $user_data['username']; ?>");
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем открывать начало PHP, если и так функция как бы пыха?

```
header("Location: " . $user_data['username']); // В переменной нужна ссылка
exit();
```

Comment: Спасибо от души!!!

Comment: @KYRAN: Но всё же не пренебрегайте советом разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Надо не механически повторять те или иные действия, не понимая их смысла, а **разобраться**, как они работают и где применяются.

`<?php echo` используется в режиме HTML

а в режиме РНР открывать тег, разумеется, не надо - он *уже* открыт.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание и совет!